# Summations with Fractional Indices (Future Value)

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, finance

> Scenario A: Assume you can invest \$40,000 each year starting at age 23 and ending at age $n$, earning a 7% return. Assume you leave the money invested until age 60.
> Scenario B: Assume you can invest \$40,000 each year starting at age $n+1$ and ending at age 60, earning a 7% return. Assume you leave the money invested until age 60.
> For what age $n$ would the account value at age 60 of Scenario A equal Scenario B?

I have set up the following sums to represent this problem:
$$\sum_{k=23}^{n}40000(1.07)^{60-k}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{60}40000(1.07)^{60-k}$$

How do you solve for $n$? You can just try all the numbers and see where they come out closest, but somehow Wolfram Alpha comes up with $n=31.1558$. A fractional number doesn't make since in the context of sum indices, so I have no idea how it's getting this.

Is there some continuous representation of the sum that it's using? How do you calculate $31.1558$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because there doesn't exist a natural indice that satisfies the equation.
From above, we have $$40000 \sum_{k=23}^{n} (1.07)^{60-k} = 40000 \sum_{k=n+1}^{60} (1.07)^{60-k}$$ so $\sum_{k=23}^{n} (1.07)^{60-k} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{60} (1.07)^{60-k}$.
Using sum of geometric series formula, we have $$\frac{{1.07}^{60-n}(1-1.07^{n-23+1})}{1-1.07} = \frac{{1.07}^{0}(1-1.07^{60-n})}{1-1.07}$$
Solving for n, $1.07^{60-n} - 1.07^{38} = 1-1.07^{60-n} \implies 1.07^{60-n} = (1+ 1.07^{38})/2$, then natural logarithm of both sides gives $(60-n)\ln 1.07 = \ln \frac{1+1.07^{38}}{2} \implies n = 60 - \frac{\ln \frac{1+1.07^{38}}{2}}{\ln 1.07} = 31.1558$.

Comment: +1 Nice reverse engineering the Wolfram Alpha solution. It;s worth pointing out that as $n$ increases the left hand expression increases while the right one decreases. The inequality reverses but not at an integer.

Comment: Is it generally accepted that the finite geometric sum formula holds for non-integer indices?

Comment: I can't give you a good answer on this, but there is a similar discussion if you want to read about it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143632/geometric-series-for-fractional-n